# How to keep subtables together without producing half-empty pages?

Tags: tables, subfig

I have two subtables placed in a continuous float environment. However, as I've tried to make clear in the example, (i) I want the subtables to be following each other. Moreover, (ii) I want to avoid having empty space between the first paragraph and the first table. (iii) None of the tables should be below the second paragraph. I'm posting my question because even after searching for similar questions concerning subtables I could find no solution. Is there a solution to my problem?
The code is below:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,a4paper]{article} %hidelinks

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Font encoding (e.g. hyphenation w/ accented characters)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % utf-8 support
\usepackage[main=english,german]{babel} % English as main language 
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype} % Adjustment of interword spacing, character protrusion etc.
\usepackage{lipsum}

\linespread{1.5}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} % ~ 1.5 line spacing
\setlength{\parskip}{2pt} % "subtle" space between parag.

\usepackage{tabu} % tabu-environment, \tabulinesep
\usepackage{booktabs} % horizontal lines in tables
\usepackage{longtable} % tables with page break
\usepackage{float} % determining the position of e.g. tables
\usepackage[font=normalsize,labelfont=bf,skip=0pt]{caption} % formatting of captions
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption} % captions for subtables / subfigures
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigure-environment

\widowpenalty=10000 % no single lines at the top of a page
\clubpenalty=10000 % no single lines at the end of a page
\displaywidowpenalty=10000 % \widowpenalty im "math mode"
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 % footnotes always on one page

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3-5]\par
%
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison of production function estimators \\[+ 2.5mm]} 
  \label{tab:comparison}
\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
  \centering  
  \caption{Gross output specification} 
  \label{tab:comparison_gross}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Model:}} \\ 
\cline{2-6} 
\\[-1.8ex] & OLS & FE & OP & LP & WD \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Capital & 0.036$^{***}$ & 0.023$^{***}$ & 0.07$^{***}$ & 0.044$^{***}$ & 0.064$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.001) & (0.005) & (0.008) & (0.009) & (0.009) \\ 
\\ 
 Labour & 0.241$^{***}$ & 0.208$^{***}$ & 0.236$^{***}$ & 0.246$^{***}$ & 0.241$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.005) & (0.009) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.001) \\ 
\\ 
 Intermediates & 0.714$^{***}$ & 0.705$^{***}$ & 0.726$^{***}$ & 0.731$^{***}$ & 0.736$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.003) & (0.006) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.001) \\ 
\\ 
 R\&D & & & & & \\ 
  & & & & & \\ 
\\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
Observations & 24,438 & 24,438 & 24,215 & 24,360 & 24,360 \\ 
No. of Firms & 5,056 & 5,056 & 5,055 & 5,047 & 5,047 \\
Returns to scale & 0.991 & 0.936 & 1.02 & 1.04 & 1.04 \\
R$^{2}$ & 0.979 & 0.857 & 0.973 & 0.973 & 0.974 \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} & \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \caption*{\textit{Continued} \\[+ 2.5mm]}
\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
  \centering
  \caption{Value-added specification} 
  \label{tab:comparison_value} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Model:}} \\ 
\cline{2-6} 
\\[-1.8ex] & OLS & FE & OP & ACF & WD \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Capital & 0.136$^{***}$ & 0.095$^{***}$ & 0.268$^{***}$ & 0.107$^{***}$ & 0.277$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.005) & (0.017) & (0.037) & (0.079) & (0.027) \\ 
\\ 
 Labour & 0.874$^{***}$ & 0.693$^{***}$ & 0.889$^{***}$ & 0.891$^{***}$ & 0.901$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.009) & (0.022) & (0.011) & (0.185) & (0.004) \\ 
\\
 R\&D & & & & & \\ 
  & & & & & \\ 
\\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
Observations & 24,438 & 24,438 & 24,215 & 24,360 & 24,360 \\ 
No. of Firms & 5,056 & 5,056 & 5,055 & 5,047 & 5,047 \\
Returns to scale & 1.01 & 0.788 & 1.16 & 0.693 & 1.19 \\
R$^{2}$ & 0.820 & 0.193 & 0.733 & 0.678 & 0.690 \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} &\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\begin{flushleft} 
\justify{
\textit{Note:} Standard errors in parentheses, clustered at the firm level. Standard errors of control function estimates are generated using 50 bootstrap repetitions and not accounting for firm exit. Controls include two-digit industry dummies, year dummies, and a dummy for East Germany. Due to zero values in the investment or the energy expenditures variables some observations are dropped.\\[+ 2.5mm] \textit{Source}: CAF AFiD panel of industrial firms, 2003-2007, covering firms in the manufacturing sector with 20 or more persons employed, own calculations.}
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
%
\lipsum[3-5]\par
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE!

Comment: the space is forced by `\pagebreak`  note also `\justify`  does not take an argument, it is intended to be used as `\begin{justify}` but is never needed anyway as justification is the default

Comment: As an alternative: all the information that are currently contained in both subtables could probably fit onto a single page if you sacrifice the somewhat excessive use of white space. Would that be an option, as well?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If I remove the page break, the tables are vertically aligned, but forced to another page. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @leandriis: The last row (R&D) is to be filled later on. Actually, I would prefer to have the two tables split with two different titles as shown in the eaxmple. I thought the subtables were well suited for this use case ;-)

Comment: it is very hard to guess what you want to do, the tables  can not split over a page so either you want later paragraphs to come before the table (as will happen if you remove the page break) or you want some of the earlier paragraphs to move after both tables, which you can do by moving the table earlier in the source

Answer (score 1):

The large space is forced by the `\pagebreak` command, removing that allows the first page to fill with text but in comments it seems you'd rather fill it with the table, so you need to move it earlie in the source so that it can fit in the `[h]` position.

[image]

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,a4paper]{article} %hidelinks

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Font encoding (e.g. hyphenation w/ accented characters)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % utf-8 support
\usepackage[main=english,german]{babel} % English as main language 
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype} % Adjustment of interword spacing, character protrusion etc.
\usepackage{lipsum}

\linespread{1.5}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} % ~ 1.5 line spacing
\setlength{\parskip}{2pt} % "subtle" space between parag.

\usepackage{tabu} % tabu-environment, \tabulinesep
\usepackage{booktabs} % horizontal lines in tables
\usepackage{longtable} % tables with page break
\usepackage{float} % determining the position of e.g. tables
\usepackage[font=normalsize,labelfont=bf,skip=0pt]{caption} % formatting of captions
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption} % captions for subtables / subfigures
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigure-environment

\widowpenalty=10000 % no single lines at the top of a page
\clubpenalty=10000 % no single lines at the end of a page
\displaywidowpenalty=10000 % \widowpenalty im "math mode"
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 % footnotes always on one page

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]\par
%
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison of production function estimators \\[+ 2.5mm]} 
  \label{tab:comparison}
\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
  \centering  
  \caption{Gross output specification} 
  \label{tab:comparison_gross}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Model:}} \\ 
\cline{2-6} 
\\[-1.8ex] & OLS & FE & OP & LP & WD \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Capital & 0.036$^{***}$ & 0.023$^{***}$ & 0.07$^{***}$ & 0.044$^{***}$ & 0.064$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.001) & (0.005) & (0.008) & (0.009) & (0.009) \\ 
\\ 
 Labour & 0.241$^{***}$ & 0.208$^{***}$ & 0.236$^{***}$ & 0.246$^{***}$ & 0.241$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.005) & (0.009) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.001) \\ 
\\ 
 Intermediates & 0.714$^{***}$ & 0.705$^{***}$ & 0.726$^{***}$ & 0.731$^{***}$ & 0.736$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.003) & (0.006) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.001) \\ 
\\ 
 R\&D & & & & & \\ 
  & & & & & \\ 
\\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
Observations & 24,438 & 24,438 & 24,215 & 24,360 & 24,360 \\ 
No. of Firms & 5,056 & 5,056 & 5,055 & 5,047 & 5,047 \\
Returns to scale & 0.991 & 0.936 & 1.02 & 1.04 & 1.04 \\
R$^{2}$ & 0.979 & 0.857 & 0.973 & 0.973 & 0.974 \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} & \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \caption*{\textit{Continued} \\[+ 2.5mm]}
\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
  \centering
  \caption{Value-added specification} 
  \label{tab:comparison_value} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Model:}} \\ 
\cline{2-6} 
\\[-1.8ex] & OLS & FE & OP & ACF & WD \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Capital & 0.136$^{***}$ & 0.095$^{***}$ & 0.268$^{***}$ & 0.107$^{***}$ & 0.277$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.005) & (0.017) & (0.037) & (0.079) & (0.027) \\ 
\\ 
 Labour & 0.874$^{***}$ & 0.693$^{***}$ & 0.889$^{***}$ & 0.891$^{***}$ & 0.901$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.009) & (0.022) & (0.011) & (0.185) & (0.004) \\ 
\\
 R\&D & & & & & \\ 
  & & & & & \\ 
\\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
Observations & 24,438 & 24,438 & 24,215 & 24,360 & 24,360 \\ 
No. of Firms & 5,056 & 5,056 & 5,055 & 5,047 & 5,047 \\
Returns to scale & 1.01 & 0.788 & 1.16 & 0.693 & 1.19 \\
R$^{2}$ & 0.820 & 0.193 & 0.733 & 0.678 & 0.690 \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} &\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\begin{flushleft} 
\textit{Note:} Standard errors in parentheses, clustered at the firm level. Standard errors of control function estimates are generated using 50 bootstrap repetitions and not accounting for firm exit. Controls include two-digit industry dummies, year dummies, and a dummy for East Germany. Due to zero values in the investment or the energy expenditures variables some observations are dropped.\\[+ 2.5mm] \textit{Source}: CAF AFiD panel of industrial firms, 2003-2007, covering firms in the manufacturing sector with 20 or more persons employed, own calculations.
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
%

\clearpage

\lipsum[4-5]\par
\lipsum[3-5]\par
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, David! Moving the table up in the source code has done the trick ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- With use of `talltblr` table (which is `tabularray` package equivalent for `threeparttable`) the table can contain notes and remarks, and also can be more compact. Therefore less space is needed for it.
- Removing `\pagebreak` (as proposed by @DavidCarlisle in his comments and answer: +1) for removing empty space above table.
- Tables are insert in group where are determined common `sisetup` for both tables

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{microtype} % Adjustment of inter word spacing, character protrusion etc.

\usepackage[main=english,german]{babel} % English as main language

\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}

\usepackage{ragged2e}  % not used
\usepackage{xcolor}    % not used
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, counter}
%
\SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\footnotesize}
\SetTblrStyle{remark}{font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.92}\selectfont}
\SetTblrStyle{remark-tag}{\par\vspace{-0.75ex}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]\par
%
\begingroup % for tables common setup
\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty  =,
    input-close-uncertainty =,
    table-format={(}1.3{$^{***}$}, 
         }
    \begin{table}[!b]
\caption{Gross output specification}
\label{tab:comparison_gross}

\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\caption{Gross output specification}
\label{tab:comparison_gross}
    \begin{talltblr}[
 label = none,
 entry = none,
note{} = {Standard errors in parentheses:
          *:    $p<0.10$,\quad
          **:   $p<0.05$,\quad
          ***:  $p<0.01$.
          },
                    ]{colspec={ l *{5}{X[c, si]} },
                     rowsep   = {1pt},
                     row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries},
                     row{1-3} = {guard},
                     row{odd[4-9]} = {abovesep=0pt, belowsep=1ex}
                     }
    \toprule
    &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}    Model
                &           &           &           &       \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    & OLS       & FE        & OP        & LP        & WD    \\
    & (1)       & (2)       & (3)       & (4)       & (5)   \\
    \midrule
Capital
    & 0.036\TblrNote{***}
                & 0.023\TblrNote{***}
                            & 0.07\TblrNote{***}
                                        & 0.044\TblrNote{***}
                                                    & 0.064\TblrNote{***}   \\
    & (0.001)   & (0.005)   & (0.008)   & (0.009)   & (0.009) \\
%    \addlinespace
Labour
    & 0.241\TblrNote{***}
                & 0.208\TblrNote{***}
                            & 0.236\TblrNote{***}
                                        & 0.246\TblrNote{***}
                                                    & 0.241\TblrNote{***}   \\
    & (0.005)   & (0.009)   & (0.004)   & (0.004)   & (0.001)   \\
%    \addlinespace
Intermediates
    & 0.714\TblrNote{***}
                & 0.705\TblrNote{***}
                            & 0.726\TblrNote{***}
                                        & 0.731\TblrNote{***}
                                                    & 0.736\TblrNote{***}   \\
    & (0.003)   & (0.006)   & (0.003)   & (0.003)   & (0.001)   \\
%    \addlinespace
R\&D
    & {?}       & {?}       & {?}       & {?}       & {?}       \\
    \midrule
Observations
    & {24,438}  & {24,438}  & {24,215}  & {24,360}  & {24,360}  \\
No. of Firms
    & {5,056}   & {5,056}   & {5,055}   & {5,047}   & {5,047}   \\
Returns to scale
    & 0.991     & 0.936     & 1.02      & 1.04      & 1.04      \\
$R^2$
    & 0.979     & 0.857     & 0.973     & 0.973     & 0.974     \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!t]
  \ContinuedFloat
\caption[]{Gross output specification -- \textit{Continued}}

\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\caption{Value-added specification}
\label{tab:comparison_value}
    \begin{talltblr}[
 label = none,
 entry = none,
note{} = {Standard errors in parentheses:
          *:    $p<0.10$,\quad
          **:   $p<0.05$,\quad
          ***:  $p<0.01$.
          },
remark{Note} = {
Standard errors in parentheses, clustered at the firm level. Standard errors of control function estimates are generated using 50 bootstrap repetitions and not accounting for firm exit. Controls include two-digit industry dummies, year dummies, and a dummy for East Germany. Due to zero values in the investment or the energy expenditures variables some observations are dropped.},
%
remark{Source} = {
CAF AFiD panel of industrial firms, 2003-2007, covering firms in the manufacturing sector with 20 or more persons employed, own calculations.}
                    ]{colspec={ l *{5}{X[c, si]} },
                     rowsep   = {1pt},
                     row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries},
                     row{1-3} = {guard},
                     row{odd[4-9]} = {belowsep=1ex}
                     }
    \toprule
    &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}    Model
                &           &           &           &       \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    & OLS       & FE        & OP        & LP        & WD    \\
    & (1)       & (2)       & (3)       & (4)       & (5)   \\
    \midrule
Capital
    & 0.136\TblrNote{***}
                & 0.095\TblrNote{***}
                            & 0.268\TblrNote{***}
                                        & 0.107\TblrNote{***}
                                                    & 0.277\TblrNote{***}   \\
    & (0.005)   & (0.017)   & (0.037)   & (0.079)   & (0.027)   \\
Labour
    & 0.874\TblrNote{***}
                & 0.693\TblrNote{***}
                            & 0.889\TblrNote{***}
                                        & 0.891\TblrNote{***}
                                                    & 0.901\TblrNote{***}   \\
    & (0.009)   & (0.022)   & (0.011)   & (0.185)   & (0.004)   \\
R\&D
    & {?}       & {?}       & {?}       & {?}       & {?}       \\
    \midrule
Observations
    & {24,438}  & {24,438}  & {24,215}  & {24,360}  & {24,360}  \\
No. of Firms
    & 5,056     & 5,056     & 5,055     & 5,047     & 5,047     \\
Returns to scale
    & 1.01      & 0.788     & 1.16      & 0.693     & 1.19      \\
$R^2$
    & 0.820     & 0.193     & 0.733     & 0.678     & 0.690     \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\endgroup
%
\lipsum[3-5]
%
\end{document}
```

[image]